# Google Script only executes one function not the return on chat response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, twitch

I'm having a problem with this code from my livestream, it functions with streamelemenets from the livestreams chat. I've repurposed a todo command script that copied text from users into a google sheet, mine is for betting for "round finished" before a match. I've expanded on the basic thing, and I've added a few things to it, like i wrote a countdown timer, and hooked the submit into that. So it doesn't accept bets when the countdown isn't running. The only thing left is the ability to run the timer script from the chat as well, that works, but for some reason it does not run both the function line, and the return line, so the bot posts a timeout message into chat(the timer starts properly), if the return is the first line, it does that but not the function. Here's my cobbled together code:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var start = (request.parameter.start || "").trim();
  if (start == '1') {
    updateCell();   
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Tippjáték elindult!'); 
  }
  else {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C1').getValue() == '0'){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Nem fut Tippjáték');
  }
  else {
  var todo = (request.parameter.todo || "").trim();
  if (todo == '') {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Tippet írnod kell!');
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([todo]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('');
    }
  }
}

function updateCell() { 
  var date = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E5").setValue(date);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var time = s.getRange('F3').getValues();
  s.getRange('F2').setValue(time);
  
  for (i=0; i<15; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(950);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E5").setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  } 
}
```

The two commands from streamelements is setup like this:

```
${customapi.https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPTPATH/exec?todo=$(queryencode "$(1:) - $(user)")}

${customapi.https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPTPATH/exec?start=$(queryencode "1")}
```

First one is just the simple submitting, and the second is how i tried to do the timer start. They are separate commands from chat.

Anyone could take a look at it? Its could be some really simple thing, but I'm not that good with scripting.

Answer (score 0):

this `var time = s.getRange('F3').getValues();`
should be this `var time = s.getRange('F3').getValue();`

I don't understand the point of this:

```
for (i=0; i<15; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(950);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E5").setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
```

Comment: My understanding is this: I have a countdown, it works where =now() refreshes every time theres a change in the sheet. So that part does a set value to the E5 cell 15 times roughly every one second. This way the countdown, thats just a deduction between the start time, the current time, and the countdown length(which is 15secs atm) recalculates every second.

My understanding is that the problem, comes from the bot wanting a "return" but the "return" shuts down everything after it, and if its after the countdown function, it takes too long so it times out.